# package.json how to deprecate a project dependency?

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json

Is it possible to mark a project dependency as deprecated without removing it from the project.

So other developers don't use it in future

---

I have a project that was built on Material-UI V4 and have recently added Mui-V5 with the intention that all new work is built on V5. I'd like developers to see an IDE warning when they import components from the old dependency.

---

One thought I had is to use `patch-package` to modify Mui-V4 and set it as deprecated in package.json but this warning only shows on `npm install`.

Comment: You are using MUI4 and MUI5 in same project? This is weird. Why not just remove v4 and migrate to v5? FWIW, if you are using ESLint, you can use [`no-restricted-imports`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-imports). If the IDEs your team members use have integrations for ESLint, then they will see warnings. You can also customize the warning message if you want. Another option is using `patch-package` to modify MUI4 and add `@deprecated` in JSDoc of each export.

Comment: @brc-dd `no-restricted-imports` is a great solution thank you. The project is large so migration will happen incrementally other wise 1) speed of feature delivery is impacted and 2) there is greater potentially for introducing bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as an answer, as the comment above worked great. ESLint's [no-restricted-imports](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-imports) rule works great for deprecating external library imports.

It can be set as following (see the docs for more examples):

```js
  rules: {
    // Deprecate redux
    'no-restricted-imports': [
      'warn',
      {
        paths: ['react-redux'],
      },
    ],
  }
```

This will show an IDE warning when importing anything from that module.

For deprecating local methods in your project, you can use the `@deprecated` JSDoc tag which will also generate a strikethrough warning in the IDE.